# set height for jquery based dropdownlist with images

Tags: asp.net, jquery, image, drop-down-menu

I have used jquery DropdownList with Images using http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown in my asp.net webpage..
problem is , im using flag images with flag name and my flag images are 64x64.. which is fine in dropDown Selection list, but when a list item is selected , 
i see only half flag... in short i need to set height of this dropdown

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a jquery issue. More of a styling issue. I assume that this dropdown is a div. Have a look in the source code if this div has an id or a class and use css to set the height.

For example:

```
#example_div {
  height: 70px;
}
```

Or first install Firebug in Firefox and play around with it by changing height of the element you need.